# Undefined references using GLUT with MinGW

Tags: windows, opengl, mingw, glut, static-linking

The initial command shown below yields the following errors while compiling an OpenGL program written in C.

```
C:\Users\razz\Desktop>gcc -Wall -ofoo mycube.c -lglut32cu -lglu32 -lopengl32
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `_imp__glClear'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `_imp__glLoadIdentity'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `_imp__glRotatef'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `_imp__glRotatef'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `_imp__glBegin'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x161): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x182): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x1e5): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x1ec): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnd'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x1fa): undefined reference to `_imp__glBegin'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x21b): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x27e): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x2a6): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnd'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x2b4): undefined reference to `_imp__glBegin'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x2d5): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x2f6): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x317): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x338): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x359): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x360): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnd'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x36e): undefined reference to `_imp__glBegin'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x38f): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x3b0): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x3d1): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x3f2): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x413): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x41a): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnd'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x428): undefined reference to `_imp__glBegin'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x449): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x46a): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x48b): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x4ac): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x4cd): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x4d4): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnd'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x4e2): undefined reference to `_imp__glBegin'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x503): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x524): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x545): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x566): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x587): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex3f'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x58e): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnd'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x595): undefined reference to `_imp__glFlush'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x59c): undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x617): undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x645): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x65d): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnable'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x66c): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x678): undefined reference to `glutSpecialFunc'
C:\Users\razz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccs833b1.o:mycube.c:(.text+0x67d): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am aware that this question has been asked before in threads titled "Undefined references using GLUT" and "GLUT program link error".

Unfortunately, much of their jargon is above me so I am not quite sure how to apply their solutions. Second, given the dozens of possible configurations depending on the OS, the compiler, the version of GLUT, etc, I am not even certain if their scenario relates to mine. Here's my scenario:

Using Windows 7 x64

Using GLUT as provided here: http://www.prinmath.com/csci5229/misc/install.html (download link is "my version of GLUT")

The C program, should you care, is the one given at http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Cube-in-OpenGL

I have MinGW installed,  and the "gcc" command works; I have already successfully compiled a simple 'Hello World' C program

The header file is located in C:\MinGW\include\GL\glut.h

I placed glut32.dll in C:\Windows\system32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64

libglut32cu.a is in C:\MinGW\lib, C:\MinGW\usr\lib, C:\MinGW\usr\lib64. I know it only needs to be one, technically, but I tried all three hoping one of them would work. The instructions at the aforementioned PrinMath site suggest trying the latter two folders, it appears, when my error occurs. He also suggests using the "-L flag to tell the linker where it is". So I have tried entering this in the command prompt:

```
gcc -Wall -ofoo mycube.c -L"C:\MinGW\lib" -lglut32cu -lglu32 -lopengl32
```

Unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: i guess you're starting with an old tutorial, but you're using windows 64bit. try MinGW 64bit instead: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glut library you downloaded was built for 32-bit programs.  It looks like your MinGW is building for a 64-bit target, which uses different names than the 32-bit (and is incompatible anyway).

Try adding the -m32 option to get MinGW to builds a 32-bit program:

```
gcc -m32 -Wall -ofoo mycube.c -L"C:\MinGW\lib" -lglut32cu -lglu32 -lopengl32
```

Note that mt 64-bit MinGW compiler (gcc version 4.6.1 (tdm64-1) from http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) gives a small clue about this problem:

```
ld.exe: skipping incompatible .\glut32\lib/libglut32cu.a when searching for -lglut32cu
ld.exe: cannot find -lglut32cu
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you for the explanation. Adding "#include<windows.h>" to the code (as suggested in another answer) also seems to solve the issue, though I am  not sure why.

Comment: @razzendahcuben: Adding windows.h as a header is neccesary to get some APIEXPORT macros. Also be aware that even in 64 bit Windows the OpenGL library is called opengl32.dll...

Answer (score 6):

At the top of the source file mycube.c you have to include

```
#include<windows.h>
```

or include

```
#include<GL/gl.h> or #include<GL/glu.h>
```

Then compile you code there will be no such type of error.

Comment: Thank you Dinesh, adding #include<windows.h> also solved the problem.

Comment: Before the fix I got an error like `GL/glut.h:43:24: error: redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'wchar_t' [-fpermissive]`. Stupidly, I tried editing the header file (commenting `typedef unsigned short wchar_t`) and got the same linkage error... Should have taken it as a clue for windows.h.

Comment: Thanks, adding #include<windows.h> to the top of the file solved the problem. Again, it needs to be placed in the first line of the file.